# How to verify hCaptcha response and ensure it is filled?

Tags: php, html, captcha

I have followed the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@hCaptcha/using-hcaptcha-with-php-fc31884aa9ea).

hCaptcha appears on my site, but the form can be submitted without attempting it. How can I make it a required field?

I have tried the following to make it required.

```
<?php
$data = array(
            'secret' => "my-secret (should start with 0x..)",
            'response' => $_POST['h-captcha-response']
        );
$verify = curl_init();
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://hcaptcha.com/siteverify");
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($verify);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

And also

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['h-captcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['h-captcha-response']))
  {
        $secret = 'your_secret_key';
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://hcaptcha.com/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['h-captcha-response'].'&remoteip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->success)
        {
            $succMsg = 'Your request have submitted successfully.';
        }
        else
        {
            $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
        }
   }
?>
```

But I get a `Notice: Undefined Index:` error. I tried to hide the error by editing `php.ini` and also by adding
 `<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>` at the top of my file, but it doesn't work.

When I try to make it required, I get an unexpected end to file error-

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {

   var hcaptchaVal = $('[name=h-captcha-response]').value;
   if (hcaptchaVal === "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Please complete the hCaptcha");
   }
});
```

Comment: `.value` should be `.val()` since you're using it on a jQuery object. P.S. that tutorial is not brilliant, it could be a lot clearer about how to integrate the code, and it also contains the mistake I've just mentioned. Although the "complete example" bit at the bottom does explain it more clearly.

Comment: Can you please show us 1) your HTML form including the captcha element, 2) more of the PHP code where you process the form submission. What's likely to be important here is how it all fits together.

Comment: P.S. the "And also" bit of code you showed us above...you realise that's the bit in the tutorial they said **not** to do? It was an example of an incorrect implementation, not something you should try and use.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hidden field in the DOM that holds the response from the hCaptcha challenge.
Use this code to get the response:
`$('[name=h-captcha-response]').val();`

`$()` transforms an elem in a jQuery object and `val()` is a function from jQuery. jQuery doesn't have `value` property.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.